# ProcessBuilder set JProgressBar

Tags: java, swingworker, jprogressbar

I'm using a processbuilder in a swingworker to execute a total of 6 commands in cmd. Is it possible to between each command's success, update the value of a JProgressBar?

These are the arrays included in the processbuilders:

```
protected String[] cmdBoot = {
    "dism /mount-wim /wimfile:boot.wim /index:2 /mountdir:mount",
    "dism /image:mount /add-driver:\"driver\" /recurse",
    "dism /unmount-wim /mountdir:mount /commit"
};
protected String[] cmdInstall = {
    "",
    "dism /image:mount /add-driver:\"driver\" /recurse",
    "dism /unmount-wim /mountdir:mount /commit"
};
```

My processbuilder looks like this:

```
// boot.wim
ProcessBuilder bootBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "cmd.exe", "/c", cmdBoot[0] + " && " + cmdBoot[1] + " && " + cmdBoot[2]
);

// install.wim
ProcessBuilder installBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "cmd.exe", "/c", cmdInstall[0] + " && " + cmdInstall[1] + " && " + cmdInstall[2]
);
```

What I want to do is between `cmdBoot[0]` and `cmdBoot[1]` set the value of a progressbar, is this possible? If so; how can I do this?

Comment: i don't think its possible, because you execute them in one line

Comment: You'd have to execute each one individually

Comment: @MadProgrammer Would that make a difference to performance? Or would it just run exactly the same?

Comment: I doubt it would have any significant effect on performance one way or another, but now you know when each process completes